# How exclude primary key field from FDbatchmove append?

Tags: database, delphi

When I want append source table to destination table by FDbatchMove component , Delphi rise this exception:
"[FireDac][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: UNIQUE constraint failed:AG2.M_key."
AG2.M_Key is  primary key of my Table.
If I can exclude primary key from batchmove, maybe can solve problem.
How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like some keys in the source table are the same as those in the destination table. In that case since you are using a unique primary key you can't simply append. Also since you need a primary key you cannot, by definition, omit it. You need to decide how you deal with duplicate keys and redefine what you are doing, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this cod i can exclude 'm_key' field from FDbatchmove append:

```
var ind:integer;
begin
 FDBatchMove1.Mappings.Clear;
 FDBatchMove1.Mappings.AddAll;
 ind:=FDBatchMove1.Mappings.IndexOfName('m_key');
 if ind<>-1 then
  FDBatchMove1.Mappings.Delete(ind);
 FDBatchMove1.Execute;
end
```